# Why can't I call a parameterized constructor with new in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

If you know the issue,

Assume I have a class A whose CTOR receives an integer;

I cannot do the following :

```
A* arr = new A[3](A(2), A(3), A(5));
```

Or any other way to initialize several members of an array.
I read around, its just not possible.

My question is why, why can I do

```
A arr[3] = {A(1), A(2), A(3)};
```

but I can not do the above? Memory-wise or whatever.

Thank you very much!

Comment: those are different things mind. Though it would make sense to be able to something like this, I am sure it's some legacy thing from C that for some reason C++ just 'has' to cripple it self with

Answer (score 9):

The reason you can't do this in current standard C++ (referred to as C++03) is historical. This will be cleaned up in the upcoming C++ standard (currently expected to be released this year, which would make it C++11), which will introduce what's called "uniform initialization syntax".

According to [Stroustrup's C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init), you can then write

```
A* p = new A[3] {A(1), A(2), A(3)};
```

There's a pretty good chance your compiler is actually already supporting this.

Comment: Uniform initialization syntax will apply to new[] too?

Comment: @Thomas: According to http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init, it does.

Comment: Interesting.  Though you need to add `[]` to your above example to match the question.

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah, FredO had just convinced me to do so in the chat... In fact, after actually _reading_ that FAQ entry (rather than just skimming over it) he seems to say nothing about dynamic arrays. `<sigh/>` Anyway, Fred found out that GCC supports this syntax, so that's the straw I'm currently clutching to...

Comment: N2215 (linked from BS's FAQ) uses `new int[]{1, 2, 3}` on page 5.  I haven't yet worked out the semantics of it in that paper, but I can't find anything about it in N3225 §5.3.4 beyond that the grammar allows the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do "uniform initialization" which is included in C++0x. I don't get why the initialization list uses `A(int)` parts, I'd just do this (which is accepted by C++98/03:

```
A arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: If `A` is a class that has an `explicit` constructor taking an `int`, you will have to explicitly invoke that for conversion: `A(42)`. I prefer to make all one-argument constructors explicit by default and stray from that only very rarely. In fact, looking back at >15 years of C++, I used implicit conversion with constantly decreasing frequency. One reason for that is that I had to go back to old code and remove it, often with great pain (lots of code to adapt), because it caused problems by kicking in at unexpected times.